# How to use bazel and cocoapods together for iOS projects?

Tags: cocoapods, bazel

I am using bazel to create an xcode project from a build file. I also want to integrate third party libraries with cocoapods. What are the steps to do this? Currently, I ran 'bazel build' to generate the .xcodeproj file, and then run 'pod install', however the 'pod install' command failed with a bunch of errors complaining the .xcodeproj file. Any ideas?

Comment: If you got error message, add them to this question would be more helpful. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: +1, please share more information, like the the relevant part of the BUILD file, output of pod install, and anything more that can help us understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Pinterest's PodToBUILD project lets you import pods as BUILD targets.

> Repositories are initialized in the Pods.WORKSPACE file with the
>   macro, `new_pod_repository`.
>
> Create the file `Pods.WORKSPACE`:
>
> Pod repositories are described using the new_pod_repository macro.
>
> ```
> new_pod_repository(
>   name = "PINOperation",
>   url = "https://github.com/pinterest/PINOperation/archive/1.0.3.zip",
> )
> ```
>
> The package `PINOperation` and the associated `objc_library` target,
>   `PINOperation`, is available for use within Bazel. The package and
>   target name are combined to form the label
>   `//Vendor/PINOperation:PINOperation`.

https://github.com/pinterest/PodToBUILD

Comment: I guess PodToBuild may not handle swift libraries, for instance RxSwift. It works great for Objective C libraries though.

Comment: seems ok - https://github.com/muizidn/movieboom-ios/tree/7320e4d2a259cc0df20b5c4de3c34805f6beda5c

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to guess what might be going wrong, but you might find [tulsi project](https://github.com/bazelbuild/tulsi) useful.